# Does changing Perl 6's $*OUT change standard output for child processes?

Tags: shell, stdout, raku

I was playing around with `shell` and how it acts when I change the standard filehandles in the calling program. [Proc](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Proc) says:

> $in, $out and $err are the three standard streams of the to-be-launched program, and default to "-", which means they inherit the stream from the parent process.

As far as I can tell, the external program doesn't use the same file handles:

```
#!/Applications/Rakudo/bin/perl6

#`(
    make an external Perl 6 program the outputs to standard handles
    )
my $p6-name = 'in-out.p6'.IO;
#END try $p6-name.unlink; # why does this cause it to fail?
my $p6-fh = open $p6-name, :w;
die "Could not open $p6-name" unless ?$p6-fh;
$p6-fh.put: Q:to/END/;
    #!/Applications/Rakudo/bin/perl6

    $*ERR.say( qq/\t$*PROGRAM: This goes to standard error/ );
    $*OUT.say( qq/\t$*PROGRAM: This goes to standard output/ );
    END
$p6-fh.close;
say $p6-name.e ?? 'File is there' !! 'File is not there';
die "$p6-name does not exist" unless $p6-name.e;

{
#`(
    Start with some messages to show that we can output to
    the standard filehandles.
    )
$*OUT.put: "1. standard output before doing anything weird";
$*ERR.put: "2. standard error before doing anything weird";
shell( "perl6 $p6-name" ).so;
}

{
#`(
    This block assigns a new filehandle to $*OUT and prints a
    message to it. I expect that message to not show up in the
    terminal.

    It then calls run-them to fire off the external process. It
    should inherit the same standard out and its standard out
    messages should not show up. But, they do.
    )
temp $*OUT = open '/dev/null', :w;
$*OUT.put: "3. temp redefine standard output before this message";
shell( "perl6 $p6-name" ).so;
}

$*OUT.put: "4. everything should be back to normal";
```

The output shows that when I open */dev/null* and assign its filehandle to `$*OUT`, the output from the current program don't show up in terminal (there's no output starting with `3.`). However, when I call `shell`, its standard output goes to the original standard output:

```
File is there
1. standard output before doing anything weird
2. standard error before doing anything weird
    in-out.p6: This goes to standard error
    in-out.p6: This goes to standard output
    in-out.p6: This goes to standard error
    in-out.p6: This goes to standard output
4. everything should be back to normal
```

I'm not worried about how to make this happen. I can create a `Proc` object and pass filehandles to it.

Is there something else going on?

Comment: The relevant code in MoarVM seems to be in [MVM_proc_shell](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/7bd72321b0f009178c1931d50c8faae6bf4a25d8/src/io/procops.c#L184). On Windows, the 1st time the script is run, it can't find the file it just created. On the second run, I observe the same behavior (after replacing `/dev/null` with `NUL`).

Answer (score 6):

By default the IO::Handle that is in `$*OUT` is bound to the low-level STDOUT filehandle given by the operating system.

`shell` and `run` just let the spawned process use the low-level STDOUT file that was given to Perl 6, unless you specify otherwise.

Perl 6 doesn't change anything about the outside environment until the moment before it spawns a new process.

---

The simplest thing to do is to give the filehandle object you want to use to the `shell` or `run` call with a named argument.

```perl6
# no testing for failure because the default is to throw an error anyway

my $p6-name = 'in-out.p6'.IO;
END $p6-name.unlink;

$p6-name.spurt(Q'put "STDOUT: @*ARGS[0]";note "STDERR: @*ARGS[0]"');

run $*EXECUTABLE, $p6-name, 'run', :out(open '/dev/null', :w);

{
  temp $*OUT = open '/dev/null', :w;
  shell "'$*EXECUTABLE' '$p6-name' 'shell'", :err($*OUT);
}
```

This results in

```
STDERR: run
STDOUT: shell
```

In the particular case of throwing away the output data, `:!out` or `:!err` should be used instead.

```perl6
run $*EXECUTABLE, $p6-name, 'no STDERR', :!err;
```

```
STDOUT: no STDERR
```

---

If you just want the data to be intercepted for you `:out` and `:err` do just that;

```perl6
my $fh = run( $*EXECUTABLE, $p6-name, 'capture', :out ).out;
print 'captured: ',$fh.slurp-rest;
```

```
captured: STDOUT capture
```

Comment: Ok, but the Proc docs say that shell inherits the streams of the parent process. Is there somewhere in the docs that discusses "Basically modifying any variable except %*ENV in Perl 6 has no outside effects."? Is this a design goal or is it an implementation issues?