# How could I subclass Perl 6's IO::Handle?

Tags: subclass, raku

How would I subclass IO::Handle? For example, I want to be able to "autoflush" by calling flush after every `say`:

```
class MyIO is IO::Handle {
    multi method say(MyIO:D: **@text --> True) {
        nextsame;
        $*ERR.say: "Flushing\n";
        self.flush;
        }
    };

Metamodel::Primitives.rebless: $*OUT, MyIO;
put $*OUT.^name;

$*OUT.say: "This is standard out";
```

But, it appears that MyIO is never called.

I figure that I might wrap say to produce the effect, but I'm more interested in the technique of simple subclasses to override some behavior. But, having said that, if there's a more Perly 6 way that the design intends for people to use.

So, some questions:

- Does Perl 6 actaully care that I reblessed it? How does it look up method names that might skip that?
- Are builtin classes especially resistent to standard OO techniques because of their sorcery and NQPness?
- Does Perl 6 discourage low level fiddling with handles, such as re-opening $*OUT on a file descriptor? (As in [Does changing Perl 6's $*OUT change standard output for child processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42505139/2766176))

Comment: A bit of future foretelling: 6.d language will have specific methods on IO::Handle you can override in your subclasses to affect *all* the write/read. Current working names are `.write-internal`, `.read-internal`, and `.eof-internal` though the names are yet to be bikeshedded and specced. A preview of their use can be seen in [current impl. of IO::Pipe](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/58900e7ba8ad31d905968d950bd9066a239320f5/src/core/IO/Pipe.pm#L25-L51)

Comment: Also note that [`nextsame` doesn't return back to the caller](https://rakudo.party/post/Perl6-But-Heres-My-Dispatch-So-Callwith-Maybe).

Comment: if you run `.perl.say for $*OUT.^find_method("say").candidates` you can see that your candidate does indeed show up. it's just not specific enough, i.e. the `$text` candidates wins over your `**@args` candidate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reblessing is sooo 90's  :-)

Why not use role composition to achieve your goal?

```
role MyWay {
    method say(|) {
        note "whee";
        nextsame
    }
}
my $*OUT = PROCESS::<$OUT> but MyWay;
$*OUT.say("foo")   # whee\nfoo
```

This basically creates a new dynamic `$*OUT` based on the existing `$*OUT` but with a new method `say` mixed in.

To answer your questions as well as I can:

- reblessing is considered something internal that you most likely don't want to do
- a lot of builtin classes are optimised for speed by not using the standard way of creating objects.  This sorta makes it difficult to subclass them.  In some cases, special code reverts to the standard way of making objects, making these classes subclassable after all (like `Date`).
- generally I would say low level fiddling is not advised as there are still internal refactors underway to make things faster, which could break your code if you're fiddling too low.

Since `say` internally uses `print`, it would be better to actually mix in your own `print` method:

```
role MyWay {
    method print(|) {
        note "whee";
        nextsame
    }
}
my $*OUT = PROCESS::<$OUT> but MyWay;
say "foo";   # whee\nfoo
```

This has the added benefit of no longer needing to call `say` as a method, because the sub version of `say` will pick up the altered `$*OUT` dynamically.